# React Web App moves horizontally on iPhone

Tags: css, iphone, reactjs, web-applications, safari

I was able to fix this a few months ago for my client. Now that we have split up the css to be processed by WebPAck for PWA status, I'm finding it came back.

The issue is that on the landing page of this test site (https://foxtail-stage.netlify.com/). The entire sites drags left and right! It's only on iPhone so I know it's yet another Safari issue.

I was able to fix it by adding x-overflow:hidden to both the .html and .body classes.

But as I said...now it's back :(

How can I fix this issue once and for all?

Comment: just love the alert that goes "Right click is banned"

Comment: @Agney I think the logic was they didn't want people to think it made their computer error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have two issues occurring:

1) regarding the `overflow-x` not working, you have an overriding style on the `body` tag which has `overflow-x: unset;` thereby making your `overflow-x: hidden;` nonexistent.

2) something in your UI is breaking out of it's container, the width on iPhone X is 414px but the composited width is 415px so you should debug your entire UI and make sure nothing is breaking out.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yep that was it. Someone snuck that in there.